# What's wrong with my links? They won't align and only one shows up

Tags: html, css

Hey so probably another newb error here - but I can't seem to figure out why my links have gone all funny. Here is the live example of what's happening right now:
http://www.marasites.com/?name=iSell&page=BingeLayout

And the codes are here for my navigation section:

```
nav {
    width: 12%;
    height: 93%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 7%;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
}
nav a {
    width: 10%;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #6b6b6b;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
    position: fixed;
    left: 8%;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #6b6b6b;;
}
nav h1{
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #6b6b6b;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
    position: fixed;
    left: 8%;
}
nav h2 {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #6b6b6b;;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
    position: fixed;
    left: 8%;
}
```

And it may be useful to see the HTML bit too:

```
<html>    
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="insidebox">
                <nav>
                    <h1>Basic:</h1>
                    <a href="url">HOME</a>
                    <a href="url">ART</a>
                    <a href="url">PETS</a>
                    <a href="url">LINK</a>
                    <a href="url">LINK</a>
                    <a href="url">LINK</a>
                </nav>
                <div id="content">
                </div>
                <header></header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So there are probably a LOT of errors in there I haven't picked up on and any feedback is useful, but how can I get my links to all appear below the H1 in order as they should do? And continue to work with a h2 tag applied to them too? Thanks ^

Comment: you have added `position:fixed` for `nav a` so they are getting stacked on above another

Comment: I see a `position:fixed` in your a-tag styling. When I turn that off, the flow restores.

Comment: Ahh thankyou very much will try with another position now :)

Comment: You're going to have a frustrating experience trying to get all those page components to align over your background image like that. Also, the design doesn't allow for easy future changes or responsive behavior. I strongly suggest that you use your browser's inspector to look at how modern sites are built. You can achieve a similar look with a modular, grid-oriented approach that will work as well on mobile.

Comment: I created the blank CSS version before I did it using an image (screenshot and edit on Photoshop)  - they are just simple requests for basic site layouts for use on a Virtual Pet Site so the simplicity is time-effective and suiting to the needs. I am going to take a look into this however and see if it works better for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

remove `position: fixed;` 
from:

1. `nav a{}`
2. `nav h1 {}`

that will fix the problem